# Trouble with NMaximize

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble with maximizing a function I am interested in. Below is the code I am using.

```
NMaximize[{(p^2)^alpha + ((c - p)^2)^alpha + (1 - (c - p)^2 - p^2)^alpha, 
  {c/2 - Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2 < p, p < c/2 + Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2, c == 1.2, alpha == 0.7}}, {p}]
```

I get the following error:

> NMaximize::bcons: "The following constraints are not valid: {alpha == 0.7, c == 1.2, c/2 - Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2 < p, p < c/2 + Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2}. Constraints should be equalities, inequalities, or domain specifications involving the variables."

Why is this happening?

Comment: `c = 1.2; alpha = 0.7;
NMaximize[
 {(p^2)^alpha + ((c - p)^2)^alpha + (1 - (c - p)^2 - p^2)^
    alpha, {c/2 - Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2 < p, 
   p < c/2 + Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2}}, {p}]`

Comment: `Plot[(p^2)^alpha + ((c - p)^2)^alpha + (1 - (c - p)^2 - p^2)^alpha, {p, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I am still interested as to why my original formulation did not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formulation doesn't work because your constraints don't involve variables. The preferred solution was posted as a comment to your question, but for making your original one work you could do:

```
NMaximize[{(p^2)^alpha + ((c - p)^2)^alpha + (1 - (c - p)^2 - p^2)^
    alpha, {c/2 - Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2 < p, p < c/2 + Sqrt[2 - c^2]/2, 
   c == 1.2, alpha == 0.7}}, {p, c, alpha}]
(*
  {1.38845, {p -> 0.6, c -> 1.2, alpha -> 0.7}}
*)
```